# Google+ Sign-in integration with API

Tags: google-plus, single-sign-on, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a website where I was allowing user logins based on my own database. I have migrated this login system to [Google+ sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button) and it worked well for UI based login workflow.

My website also allows users to perform some operations through our custom REST API. I want my API users to go through google sign-in as well. Does google provide a standard workflow where our end-users authenticate themselves from google and send auth token to my API?

If there is no standard workflow defined by google, I have thought of hack-ish way where users use [google refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) as API key. I will not store refresh token in DB, rather Users will send the refresh key to my API in form of API access key. API will generate access token from google. Users will use the access token as session key for further requests (for abt 1 Hr). Is it right way to go forward? Is there any security flaw in this?